# How to enable syntax conceal only in certain contexts in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax

I want to conceal variables with names based on Greek symbols and turn them into their Unicode equivalent symbol, similarly to how [vim-cute-python](https://github.com/ehamberg/vim-cute-python) works. For instance, I have this:

```
syntax match scalaNiceKeyword "alpha" conceal cchar=α
```

defined in a file for concealing within Scala files which works great except that it's overly aggressive. If I write `alphabet` it then gets concealed to become `αbet`, which is noticeably wrong.

How can I modify or expand this conceal statement so that it only conceals keywords that match `[ _]alpha[ _]`? In other words, I want the following conversions:

```
alpha_1 => α_1
alpha => α
alphabet => alphabet
```

**Note:** This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057028/how-can-i-get-context-dependent-syntax-coloring-for-the-same-keyword-in-vim), however it seems like it's slightly more complicated since the group environment I want to match is spaces and underscores.  Naively defining a syntax region like the following makes things all kinds of wrong:

```
syn region scalaGreekGroup start="[ _]" end="[ _]"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `:syntax match scalaNiceKeyword '\<alpha\>' conceal cchar=α` work as expected?

Comment: Yup, that works as expected, it doesn't conceal things like `alpha_1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the pattern to match only the names delimited by word
boundaries or underscores:

```
:syntax match scalaNiceKeyword '\(_\|\<\)\zsalpha\ze\(\>\|_\)' conceal cchar=α
```

Comment: This only solves half of the problem and under matches things.  Your suggestion seems to work equivalently to `syntax keyword scalaNiceKeyWord Alpha conceal cchar=Α`

What I really want is something that matches `alpha_1` and turns it into `α_1` while not matching `alphabet`.

Comment: @fozziethebeat:  I have missed that detail.  The answer is updated.

Comment: awesome!, that's a little gnarly looking but it works nicely.  Is it at all possible to not conceal the underscores?  `1_alpha_2` becomes `1α2` which is readable but a little funky.

Comment: @fozziethebeat:  Sure, it is possible.  Use the `\zs` and `\ze` atoms to set the start and end of the match to conceal, just like in the update of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

there's a script called [`unilatex.vim`](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=284) which defines `imaps` to do `\alpha => α` on opening/writing and backconversion on saving. I am using it for latex code and have modified it to drop backconversion as my latex compiler is able to do unicode right.
I don't know if scala source code can be unicode, but if it can be you might have a look at [my version](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/tree/master/vim/ftplugin/tex).

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could do that.  This sounds a little heavy handed though, I'd rather just conceal things without actually changing the characters.