# Can Vim display BOL whitespace as a special character?

Tags: vim

Sublime (a text editor) can display beginning of line whitespace as a special character like `--->`:

```
function foo() {
--->if (true) {
--->--->alert(true);
--->}
}
```

It's helpful in some cases. So I want to let Vim to do the same thing. I tried using `:set list`, but this options only display tab characters as `^I`, it doesn't display whitespace. Is there some way to do that like it is possible in Sublime?

Comment: Have you tried `:set invlist` ?

Comment: @alex `invlist` just do the same thing as `list`: display `EOL` & `TAB`, it doesn't display whitespace.

Comment: I use `set listchars=trail:◃,nbsp:•` to display • when there's a non-breaking space, and ◃ when there's a trailing one. This doesn't answer your question but it maybe useful. ;)

Comment: @SamyDindane thanks for your tip, display trailing whitespace is helpful, but I want to display BOL whitespace at the same time.

Comment: you can also use indent-guides

Comment: @epsilonhalbe indent-guides is a excellent plugin, but it can't use special characters to indicate BOL whitespace.

Comment: hmm maybe you can try to take kind of this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477857/vim-syntax-conceal-in-context and try to conceal 4 whitespaces as keyword and use "--->" as a substitute?

Comment: Have you tried what I propose in my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697557/254635)?  Please, let me know whether that hack is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight BOL white space, this will not insert a special character like you ask, but it will at least make it stand out by assigning it a specific color.

```
:highlight BOLWhitespace guibg=red ctermbg=red
:match BOLWhitespace /^\s\+/
```

The first line will create a highlight group called BOLWhitespace and give it the color red (might want to use something a bit more subtle). The second line will activate this highlight for all white space at the beginning of lines.

Maybe this is an acceptable compromise?

Comment: Yes, I know Vim can highlight BOLWhitespace, and the plugin indent-guides can do more with highlight. But I want to display some special characters like `set list`

Answer (score 0):

One can effectively emulate such arrows using the conceal feature
(see `:help conceal`):

```
function! EnableIndentArrows()
    exe 'syntax match NonText ''\%(^\%( \{'.&sw.'}\)*'.
    \   ' \{0,'.(&sw-2).'}\)\@<= '' transparent conceal cchar=┈'
    exe 'syntax match NonText ''\%(^\%( \{'.&sw.'}\)*'.
    \   ' \{'.(&sw-1).'}\)\@<= '' transparent conceal cchar=>'
    set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nc
endfunction
```